# Android MySQL-PHP Database String not pass Issue

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql

Here are the Android MySQL-PHP database codes. Database and Table created successfully. But when passing the value from text box to table, value does not pass but instead, blank row is generated in the table.

The error is:

> String not pass in database table ...blank row generate in table...no error generated ....issue in returning the value....

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void ,String> {

    AlertDialog alertDialog;

    Context ctx;
    BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        String reg_url = "http://127.0.0.1/webapp/register.php";
        String login_url = "http://127.0.0.1/webapp/login.php";

        String method = params[0];
            if (method.equals("register")) {
                String name = params[1];
                String user_name = params[2];
                String user_pass = params[3];

            try {
                URL url = new URL(reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));

                String data = URLEncoder.encode("user","UTF-8") + "="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8") + "="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_pass","UTF-8") + "="+URLEncoder.encode(user_pass,"UTF-8");

                                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();

                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return "Registration Success...";

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        else if (method.equals("login")){

            String login_name = params[1];
            String login_pass = params[2];

            try {
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));

                String data = URLEncoder.encode("login_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("login_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_pass,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String response = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){

                    response +=line;
                }

                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return response;


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result.equals("Registration Success...")) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {

            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
        }

    }
```

PHP code for registration

```
<?php
require "init.php";
$name      = $_POST["name"];
$user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
$user_pass = $_POST["user_pass"];
$sql_query = "insert into user_info values('$name','$user_name','$user_pass');";
if (mysqli_query($con, $sql_query)) {
    echo "<h2>Data Insertion Success</h2>";
} else {
    echo "Data Insertition Error";
}
?>
```

Comment: run the code after creating the database and table and check what is the issue...

Comment: Take the ----public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask {----in the code.....

Comment: where is the PHP code? PLUS does this code really calls your php page? using this IP `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: <?php
require "init.php";

$name = $_POST["name"];
$user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
$user_pass = $_POST["user_pass"];


$sql_query = "insert into user_info values('$name','$user_name','$user_pass');";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query))
{
echo "<h2>Data Insertion Success</h2>";
}
else
{
echo "Data Insertition Error";
}


?>PHP code for registration

Comment: are you sure the params are full at Android side? try to add a log line for `data` before `.write(data)`, something like this `Log.i("MYTAG","posting to register.php: data="+data );` and check logcat to see output

Comment: issue still not solve......@prashhh

Answer (score 0):

```
//you need to encode ONLY the values of the parameters
String param=”param1=” + URLEncoder.encode(“value1″,”UTF-8″)+
“&param2=”+URLEncoder.encode(“value2″,”UTF-8″)+
“&param3=”+URLEncoder.encode(“value3″,”UTF-8″);
```